# How to change a user password using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm writing a kind of `passwd` command line app to change an Azure account's password. Something to work like this:

```
> passwd someuser Passw*rd1
```

After reading all the documentations, I have my application created in Azure portal with all the permissions needed and I'm about to get the app authorization, just before getting the access token.

Problem is instead of getting the authorization code what the call for `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantName>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` returns to me is an HTML page.

As far as I understand, this page is supposed to give the signed-in user the chance to delegate the required permissions, but this is a command to be used by an administrator user. In fact, there is no signed-in user at this moment.

What am I missing?

Comment: The question is about changing a password, just like the code example shows, so the text is consistent with the question. The detail about the getting the access token is just to clarify the stage of the process I was stuck. Even thought, someone else was able to read the question carefully enough and posted the exact answer for my problem, which was accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a code sample about resetting user password.

```
$tennantid        = ''         
$SubscriptionId   = ''         
$ApplicationID    = ''         
$ApplicationKey   = ''
$TokenEndpoint = {https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token} -f $tennantid 
$ARMResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

$Body = @{
        'resource'= $ARMResource
        'client_id' = $ApplicationID
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
        'client_secret' = $ApplicationKey
        'scope' = 'https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FDirectory.AccessAsUser.All'
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}
    Body = $Body
    Method = 'Post'
    URI = $TokenEndpoint
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("authorization","Bearer $($Token.access_token)")
$ResetPwd = @{
    "passwordProfile" = @{
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn" = "false"
        "password" = "Test123456!"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method Patch -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/$($respons.id)" -ContentType "application/json" -Body $ResetPwd
```

Then used this and the code above works.

```
$servicePrincipal = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName ServicePrincipalName
$roleId = (Get-MsolRole -RoleName "Company Administrator").ObjectId
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $roleId -RoleMemberObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This is the correct answer because I could do exactly what I wanted without requiring the authorization

Answer (score 0):

Where are you call the `/authorize` endpoint?

You could call it like this in a browser and log in with your account:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
&state=12345
```

Then you will get a "code" in the address bar.
Use this code to request access token:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh
```

See details from [Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) and [Request an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token).

Comment: Sorry for taking a bit long to get back. Unfortunately your answer still does not solve my problem. What I get when I post the first request you suggested is an HTML page. This page is the first one of the credential entering dialog, asking for user name and then password. However, what I want is a silent process. I want work as an administrator, just setting a certain user his/her password without having to openly login to Azure. I have an administration user with the correct premissions to set someoneselse's password, so I want to use this one user as the implicit logged in user.